# Advanced Digitizing Panel angle units

Tags: qgis, digitizing, units, angles

I have QGIS 2.18.3 installed. I'm trying to change angle units from degrees to Gon/gradians (90 degrees = 100 Gon).

I navigated to Settings--> Options --> Map Tools --> Preferred angle units, and changed it from "degrees" to "Gon/gradians".

It seems that Gons/Gradians are applied to measurement tools, but not for the Advanced Digitizing tools. Is there any way to get Gons/Gradians also to work in Advanced Digitizing tools as input angle units?

Bellow are the results (after hitting "OK" and restarting QGIS)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is currently possible to change the angle units of the *Advanced Digitizing tool*. Degrees are tend to be used and described in the [Editing documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=advanced%20digitizing#snapping-settings). You could try submitting a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis), I could not find an existing one which mentioned changing the units of angles.

---

One method I used (it was for radians but can be applied to grads) is to type in the conversion value inside the angle box which for gradians to degrees would be:

```
(9/10)*degrees
```

So if we wanted to set a line at `100 gradians` (or `90 degrees`), we could type in

```
(9/10)*100
```

[image: Example]

Then when we press *Enter*, the angle is calculated in degrees and is automatically **locked** so you could continue to digitize at said angle:

[image: Result]

---

The caveat is that you would have to type in the values each time instead of using the cursor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! So it seems there is a feature missing, which is why I can't hope for a definitive answer. This method of yours does the job well enough with current tools available. Maybe I'll try to put in a feature request, even though I suspect this goes to "low priority" request. Again, many thanks yet again for your help!

Comment: @Gifupack - Most welcome! There could be a definitive answer (although I'm not aware of one). Even if it goes to the "low priority" list, if it's easy enough to do then it might not take long to implement. And chances are, others would also find this feature useful :)